# Devise - What controller do I put before_filter :skip_trackable in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to get login working via an api using devise. From the documentation:

> If you are using token authentication with APIs and using trackable.
>   Every
>        request will be considered as a new sign in (since there is no session in
>        APIs). You can disable this by creating a before filter as follow:
>
> ```
>    before_filter :skip_trackable
>
>    def skip_trackable
>      request.env['devise.skip_trackable'] = true
>    end
> ```

Where should I put this method and before filter? The sessions_controller, the users_controller?

Will using this remove trackable for regular web login/registration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add it to the controller that requires authentication. I would recommend creating a base controller for all of your API controllers to extend.

Make sure skip_trackable is called before authenticate_user.

```
class Api::BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :skip_trackable
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :json

  def skip_trackable
    request.env['devise.skip_trackable'] = true
  end
end
```